# I'm trying to install Oracle Java sdk at the final i'm getting Error

Tags: software-installation, java

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: check if java is installed correctly on your system. open a terminal and perform: `javac -version` or `java -version`

Comment: What's the output of `uname -m` and `file /usr/bin/java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the wrong binaries.

Install Oracle Java with a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And configure alternatives for Java

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: webupd8team to the rescue!

Comment: does this install jre or jdk? "java" is not very informative